# How fast is the angle of elevation changing?

Tags: calculus, related-rates

[image]

Here is the situation

[image]

We need to find $\dfrac{ d \alpha }{d t }$

In vectorial notation, we write the speed of the drone as

$$ V = (20 \cos 30, 20 \sin 30) = (10 \sqrt{3}, 10) $$

Let's say $t$ seconds have elapsed and we have that the horizontal component of drone distance is

$$ 10 \sqrt{3} t $$

and therefore

$$ \tan \alpha = \frac{2}{10 \sqrt{3} t } $$

or

$$ \alpha = \tan^{-1} (1/10\sqrt{3}t) $$

AND THUS

$$ \frac{d \alpha}{d t } = - \frac{1}{10 \sqrt{3} t^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + (1/10\sqrt{3}t)^2 } $$

Is this correct?

Comment: This is a very poorly worded problem. No information is given about the height of an observer so one must assume all measurements are with respect to a coordinate system centered at ground level. Furthermore, no information is given about the direction of the drone other than the angular elevation of its path wrt the horizon. Is the projection of the direction vector toward the origin? Away from the origin? Some other direction. Since no information is given about this one can assume it is either flying away or flying toward the origin. That will yield two different but equally valid answers.

Comment: I think then the relation should be 
$$ \tan \alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} t } $$
do you agree?

Comment: @ILoveMath Do you have the answer for this problem? Maybe, it's from a textbook that has answers to problems at the back.

Comment: no solution key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the way you understand the term "downrange" seems to be wrong. It's actually a horizontal distance. Not vertical. Here's what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downrange) says about it:

> **Downrange** is the horizontal distance traveled by a spacecraft, or the spacecraft's horizontal distance from the launch site.

Secondly, nowhere in the problem does it say that the drone is 2 meters downrange from the tip of your head. It says from you! So, we have to assume that, as John Wayland Bales aptly mentioned in his comment, all measurements are with respect to a coordinate system centered at the ground level.

Here's how the problem can be represented graphically:

[image]

$x$, $y$ and $\theta$ are quantities that change with time. Let's find the relationships between them:

$$
\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}=\frac{y}{x}\implies y=\frac{x}{2},\\
\tan{\theta}=\frac{y}{2}\implies \tan{\theta}=\frac{x}{4}\implies \theta=\tan^{-1}{\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)}.
$$
Now, let's take that last result with the angle theta and differentiate both sides of that equation with respect to time (don't forget that $\theta$ and $x$ are functions of time):

$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{4}{16 + x^2}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}$$

We know what $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is. But what is $x$ equal to? When $y$ is 10 meters, $x$ is going to be 20 meters:
$$y=\frac{x}{2}\implies x=2y=2\cdot 10=20\ m.$$
Thus:
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{4}{16 + 20^2}\cdot 20=\frac{5}{26}\ rad/s.$$